# Cannot get CKEditor value w/ Jquery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am referencing the CKEditor JQuery adapter (as well as jquery 1.6 lib)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js" />
```

And declaring, my CKEditor instance as:

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
toolbar : 'Basic',
uiColor : '#0579b3',
resize_enabled: false
}); 
</script>
```

In Jquery I am doing:

```
var value = $('textarea.editor1').getData();
```

If I try to alert the var value, I get undefined.

Is there something wrong with how I am trying to get the textarea value w/ JQuery?
I have also tried .val() but no luck.

The alert happens after a button is pressed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
var value = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();

//or
$('#editor1').ckeditor(function( textarea ){
  $(textarea).val();
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried the first one and worked for me, calling the element ID without the #, as you created the CKEditor element.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could integrate a function on JQuery

```
jQuery.fn.CKEditorValFor = function( element_id ){
  return CKEDITOR.instances[element_id].getData();
}
```

and passing as a parameter the ckeditor element id

```
var editor1_value = $().CKEditorValFor('editor1');
```